# Django Admin can't find Media files

Tags: django, admin

I'm unable to get the media files served up for my django admin after I set my settings like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In reference to having my settings like this, something I read said "Admin will need to have its CSS, images and javascript code in this location — you’ll have to copy them from django/contrib/admin/media/."

Having to copy the media files seems like the wrong way to do it.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I symlink the Django files instead of copying them.

```
ln -s /path/to/project/media/admin /path/to/django/contrib/admin/media/
```